# merge sql results in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got a the following query

```
    select tb2.customer_no, tb2.last_name, tb2.first_name
    from ccare.customer tb2
    where tb2.customer_no = '1000647'
```

which outputs

```
             customer_no    First name      Last name
             1000647          George              Roberts
```

How can I combine the First name and last name to appear in one column. The desired output would be

```
             customer_no       Name     
             100064        George Roberts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple. This should do it.

```
select tb2.customer_no, tb2.last_name || ' ' || tb2.first_name name
from ccare.customer tb2
where tb2.customer_no = '1000647'
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Use `||` to concatenate strings, not `+`. I haven't used Oracle sql in a while.